# Web.py Apache mod_wsgi url rewrite

Tags: python, apache, web.py

I believe I have Apache setup correctly with mod_wsgi and Rewrite Engine. I'm using web.py to serve up content. The test "Hello World" app works but the output includes the file root.
Looks like this:

```
Hello, /var/www/example.com/application/!
```

I've included the config and code.

Here is the apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName foodcost.mynetwork.inside
    ServerAlias foodcost.mynetwork.inside
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/example.com/application/

    Alias /static /var/www/example.com/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/example.com/application>
      SetHandler wsgi-script
      Options ExecCGI
      Options +FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>

    AddType text/html .py

    <Location />
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/.*)+code.py/
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ code.py/$1 [PT]
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Python Code:

```
import web

urls = (
    '(.*)', 'hello'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=False)
application = app.wsgifunc()

class hello:
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name:
            name = 'World'
        return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

*Update*: After playing around with the Rewrite I have come to discover that the problem is with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ code.py/$1 [PT]`. The `$1` (parameter) passes the root of where the python script is running plus whatever the rest of the URL is from the root url.

So an example of this would be URL:

```
http://{rootURL}/tom
```

Output:

```
Hello, /var/www/example.com/application/tom!
```

I can't figure out why the directory location of the python script is being passed in.

Comment: Why do you think you need to rewrite the URLs? The `WSGIScriptAlias` should serve your application directly, without any need for rewriting.

Comment: I am using this tutorial to set things up. http://www.codero.com/knowledge-base/questions/316/How+to+deploy+web.py+applications

I am would like the url not to show the code.py.

Comment: @Jeremy: That's where WSGIScriptAlias comes in; it takes a root URL and uses your WSGI script to server that URL. `code.py` will never be part of the URL in such a configuration.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I do not want code.py to show up in my URL. This all works except that the parameter that is passed to my python script is the file path to the script. I can not figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the tutorial at http://webpy.org/cookbook/mod_wsgi-apache, I believe you really don't need to rewrite URLs. Your apache config is then:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName foodcost.mynetwork.inside
    ServerAlias foodcost.mynetwork.inside
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/example.com/application/code.py/
    Alias /static /var/www/example.com/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/example.com/application>
      SetHandler wsgi-script
      Options ExecCGI
      Options +FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>

    AddType text/html .py

</VirtualHost>
```

(among other changes, note the added `code.py/` to the `WSGIScriptAlias` directive.)

And the file `/var/www/example.com/application/code.py` is:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'hello'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=False)
application = app.wsgifunc()

class hello:
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name:
            name = 'World'
        return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

(note the added slash in the `urls` tuple in the beginning.

This way there's no "code.py" showing up:

[image]